# Devexpress xtragrid Checklistbox show first word item checked

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I use `xtragrid` , i have a colum is checklistbox:

```
new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem ("D", "Doctor"), 
new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem ("P", "Patient"), 
new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem ("O", "Other Companies"), 
new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem ("R", "Related Companies")});
```

When I selectd a checkbox I want it to show the following:  (D,P,O,R) not Doctor,Patient....

[image]

Comment: Sr , this link img : http://s1376.photobucket.com/user/nnquang207/media/Untitle12_zpsiulnr2au.png.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the CheckedComboBoxEdit control's [CustomDisplayText event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_CustomDisplayTexttopic):

```
private void checkedComboBoxEdit1_CustomDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    e.DisplayText = e.Value.ToString();
}
```